# MLP: Relation between number of iteration and accuracy

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to ask somebody for advice. I created programme in C++ where I am using OpenCV library (v2.4.11), especially MLP classifier.

I have had accuracy on 2 000 testing screens about 92% but only when I set number of iterations on **1**. With bigger numbers like 100, 1000 it is getting worse (on 100 it is 78%, on 1000 77%).

It is possible that problem is in data model and programming part is correct? Or it has to be my fault?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is possible that problem is in data model and programming part is
>   correct?

Yes, the number of iterations, like the number of neurons and the number of layers, is one of the parameters that has great impact on the overall performance of the MLP classifier. The more iterations you apply to the MLP training the more the MLP NN adapts/fits to its training data. This leads to high performance on training data but can eventually lead to poor performance on test data. In this case you have [**over-train/over-fit**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) your MLP NN.

There are however [methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization) (e.g., grid-search) for the optimization of the parameters of a classifier.

Comment: It was really caused by overtrain of classifier. I trained 224 000 samples, now I am training 12 800 samples and with increasing amount of iteration are results better. Thank you for your help.